# save several bash screens of program input/output

Tags: terminal, logs, output, gnome-terminator

I work in Maxima a lot (start it on the terminal with "rlwrap .../maxima" and sometimes I want to save a few (several) screens worth (scrolling) of calculations.

I realize I can use xmaxima, a variant that can then save it to a text file - that works. But I also sometimes use scipy/python in the terminal, or even others.

In general, is there a way to save several screens of interactive program input/output from the bash terminal to a file (possibly preserving 'word art', or 2D display)?

I use terminator, though not sure it matters. Also, sometimes I work on a debian system and other times on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what the `script` tool is for.  It will save an entire terminal session - inputs and outputs:

```
$ script sessionlog.txt
[ do stuff ]
$ exit
$ ls sessionlog.txt
```

Comment: Wow, super cool! I hadn't heard of it before so thanks, but I am getting lots of weird symbols in the output file. Unfortunately I couldn't even get something like `org' from emacs to work either.

Comment: Those strange characters in the output file are what move the cursor around and change character cell colours.  If you `cat` the file you'll see exactly what you saw when you made the recording.  As it's a _complete_ record of everything that happens, you'll see everything that transpired, including mistakes you made, backspaced over, and corrected.

Comment: I see... yeah, an editor does show those symbols, while `cat' doesn't.... I tried `cat scriptOut.txt > scriptOut2.txt' but it is not any cleaner. I also looked at the man pages but no idea of how to not caputre those symbols...

Comment: If you remove those symbols, you are removing the data required to accurately recreate your terminal session.

Comment: maybe my question wasn't clear... maxima, python, reduce, and other similar programs (I don't know about all), wouldn't need these symbols at all. I was thinking of something like org for emacs, or saving  a session in xiki, or... but this is cool tool for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Especially since you're *already* using `rlwrap`:

`rlwrap` has a `--logfile` (shorter:`-l`) option that will save the entire session (all *edited* input lines, and all output from the rlwrapped command) to a file:

```
rlwrap --logfile log.txt ../maxima
```

`script` is brilliant, but will also save all your typos and their corrections, which may be more than you need. `rlwrap` doesn't record anything until you enter a line, and then remembers only that line (and any command output that comes after it)